# NetSutie Adding Image to Landing Page

Tags: netsuite

I am new to NetSuite and have very little training. I want to update an image on a landing page for a product and I can not do it on the site using the editor on the website. It has to be done on NetSuite. I cat seem to find the code for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for. I found the image that was on the page, in the file cabinet and opened it up and clicked on upload file and there I uploaded the new image and it worked for me.